# Existence of Continuous Function respecting points

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, metric-spaces

Suppose that $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d)$ are metric spaces between which there exists a continuous function.  Fix $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$.  When does there exist a continuous function sending $x$ to $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(z):=y$ for all $z \in X.$ Then $f$ is continuous anf $f(x)=y.$

Comment: If I also assume that $Y$ is not a point and $f$ is injective, then is it still possible to define such a function?

Comment: @AIM_BLB Not in general. There's no injective map from $[0,1]$ to any countable metric space. $Y$ being a point isn't really relevant though.

Comment: True, thanks jgon.  Would you know if there is a non-trivial characterization of when this is possible?